# Como ajustar dataframe con Multiindex en python

Tags: dataframe, multi-index

Al graficar por fecha el contenido del dataframe, como pueden ver a continuación son tantas las columnas que no se logra entender la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ende quisiera graficar por columnas, es decir, dejar solo en el dataframe la columna fecha y por supuesto una ciudad, entonces dejar por ejemplo la columna BELLO y la columna fecha y poder observar la grafica con estos dos elementos, sin embargo, como es un dataframe con multiindexe No tengo conocimiento como hacerlo, me podrían por favor ayudar?, dejo resaltado en amarillo las columnas que quisiera dejar pero ir agregando o retirando a medida de mis necesidades

Comment: Utiliza `df.droplevel` y quita los niveles innecesarios, por lo que veo "CIUDAD" y "count" No hacen nada, todas las ciudades pertenecen a esos dos por lo que puedes simplemente eliminar esos dos niveles

Comment: Muchas gracias  HeytalePazguato, funcionó perfecto. Tendencia_robo_x_municipio.columns =  Tendencia_robo_x_municipio.columns.droplevel(0)